# Как выбрать БД для миграции в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Как выбрать БД для миграции в laravel?

Comment: Что вам мешает посмотреть с какими бд работает laravel?

Comment: Возможно он имеет ввиду что у него несколько бд (физических) ?

Answer (score 3):

Есть два способа, но одна деталь общая:

В файле конфига app/config/database.php

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(
        // Первая база
        'mysql' => array(      
        ),

        // Вторая база
        'mysql2' => array(            
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

1-й способ: В файле миграции:

```
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('some_table', function($table)
{

});
```

2-й способ: `php artisan migrate --database=mysql2`

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто -

- Если загляните в фасад **Schema** то увидите метод:

  ```
  public static function connection($name)
  {
      return static::$app['db']->connection($name)->getSchemaBuilder();
  }
  ```
- Так-же ответ есть в **конструкторе класса**:

  ```
  public function __construct(Connection $connection)
  {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->grammar = $connection->getSchemaGrammar();
  }
  ```
- Ну и самый скучный способ - прочитать в [доке](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema):

> To specify which connection the schema operation should take place on,use the  Schema::connection method:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

А само **подключение должно быть прописанно** в `config/database.php`

*Массив* `connections`.

```
'connections' => [
    'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

Comment: ну это неподходящий способ. --database=mysql2 консоль не понимает

Comment: @JonnyManowar комментом вы промазали) А вообще если запустить миграции оно их выполнит к той базе к которой сейчас подключено

Comment: @JonnyManowar а способ указанный коллегой тоже должен работать - проверьте существует ли ваше подключение которое вы прописываете и коректное ли оно, если у вас старая версия laravel впишите `php artisan help migrate`